# how to make drawable on dynamic canvas

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, canvas, html5-canvas

I have display canvas dynamically based on records in db. Currently I have
two records in db and it shows two canvas in page.Now i should able to draw
on both cannvas however I can only draw on last canvas not on the both canvas.
Please check the image https://ibb.co/n7rvdk5  for more.
I am getting id 609 and 610.It can be 1,2 etc. This id are passed on canvas id to make it unique.

```
<div class="snap-field col-sm-12" style="height: 450px;"> 

    loop here
    <canvas data-fieldid="{{$draw->id}}"  
        id="image-canvas-{{$draw->id}}"
        width="400" height="200"  
        class="image-canvas"
        style="position:absolute;">
    </canvas>
  

</div>
```

This is my js part and within document.ready function i have loaded the canvas . initEditableImageCanvas takes unique id. for example in this case it takes 609 and 610.I can draw on canvas with id 610 but not on 609.Maybe I need to make some changes here and I am not sure what should I do

```
<script>
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "red",
    y = 2;

function initEditableImageCanvas(fieldId) {

    canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas-' + fieldId);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);



}

function draw() {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}



function findxy(res, e) {


    if (res == 'down') {

        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            draw();

        }
    }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image-canvas").each(function(canvas) {
        //get id 
        initEditableImageCanvas($(this).data("fieldid"));
    });
});
</script>
```

I am looking for help to fix it. I want draw in all canvas.
Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw on a canvas, you can store it in a variable so that you are able to apply your logic.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
/*   
   Logic   
*/
```

However, in your case, it turns out that since `canvas` and `ctx` are global variables, they get reassigned each time `initEditableImageCanvas()` is called within jQuery's `each()`.

So even though the function `findxy()` is called whenever one event (i.e. `mousemove`) happens, it's not sufficient to draw on the right places. You
have to check if it is pointing to the right canvas.

---

This said, to prevent unexpected behaviors, prefer using local variables defined with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement instead of global ones when working with multiple drawable `canvas`. One solution follows:

1. Change `var` -> `let`
2. Add a third parameter (`c`) to `findxy()`
3. Add an parameter (`ctx`) to `draw()`

```js
// get rid of global canvas and ctx    
var flag = false,
  prevX = 0,
  currX = 0,
  prevY = 0,
  currY = 0,
  dot_flag = false;

var x = "red",
  y = 2;

function initEditableImageCanvas(fieldId) {
  // use let
  let canvas = document.getElementById('editable-image-canvas-' + fieldId);
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  /* 
     Attach this to each findxy 
  */
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    findxy('move', e, this)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    findxy('down', e, this)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    findxy('up', e, this)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    findxy('out', e, this)
  }, false);



}

function draw(ctx) {
  // added parameter ctx
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = x;
  ctx.lineWidth = y;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}



function findxy(res, e, c) {
  // added parameter c and local ctx
  let ctx = c.getContext('2d')

  if (res == 'down') {

    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = x;
      ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      dot_flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      draw(ctx); // added argument

    }
  }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".editable-image-canvas").each(function(canvas) {
    // alert($(this).data("fieldid")) //give id 609 and 610
    initEditableImageCanvas($(this).data("fieldid"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snap-field col-sm-12" style="height: 450px;"> <div style="display:grid;"> <span>609</span> <canvas data-fieldid="609" id="editable-image-canvas-609" width="200" height="150" class="editable-image-canvas" style="position:relative;top:10%;border:1px dotted; margin-bottom:30px;"> </canvas> <span>610</span> <canvas data-fieldid="610" id="editable-image-canvas-610" width="200" height="150" class="editable-image-canvas" style="position:relative;top:10%;border:1px dotted;"> </canvas> </div><input type="hidden" name="field_{{$draw->id}}" id="editable-image-hidden-{{$draw->id}}"></div>
```

Comment: A breakdown and explanation of those "minor changes" would make this answer better ... always remember you are not just solving the problem but providing an explanation to  anyone in the future having a similar issue

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it  @HelderSepulveda, I'll try my best to improve my next answers

Comment: +1 ... yes improve next answers, but Is not too late to improve this one, hit that Edit button and add some explanation

Comment: Hi, it's working for me. Did you remember to change the src according to their `fieldId`? Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/ngk1xc6L/